# Quotes not around values in CSV

Tags: .net-core, servicestack

I'm using `ToCsv()` on a collection to convert it to CSV text.

None of the values have quotes around them - even when there are spaces in them.

How do I switch quotes on?

Comment: It would still make it valid CSV with spaces. quotes would be introduced it the value has `,` commas in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV fields only need to be quoted if they contain delimiters, line breaks or quotes themselves.